# While Edit Text is focused relative layout went on top in android

Tags: android

In my application i am using 3relative layouts. First one for header, second one for content part,in this part it have spinner and one edit text and third one for footer, it have one spinner. Android keyboard popup while i selecting the edit text that time my 3rd relative layout spinner move into top of the screen. how to fix this problem.

Comment: add to the config changes of your activity the soft keyboard

Comment: thanks for reply. now that problem solved. i used android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" this one in android manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are ste of options..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

under your Activity tag in manifest should do the job..